# GCP AppEngine Permissions

Tags: cron, google-cloud-platform, user-permissions, google-app-engine

I need to grant a GCP project user permissions so he is able to run cron tasks from the app engine console. I've been looking around and could not find suitable permissions for that.
Any tip??

Comment: roles/appengine.appAdmin

Comment: You will need to set one of "Cloud Scheduler" roles.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the permission required to do this is `cloudscheduler.jobs.run`, which is provided by the `Owner`, `Editor`, `roles/cloudscheduler.jobRunner`, or `roles/cloudscheduler.admin` roles.

See [the IAM permissions reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference)

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron#before_you_begin), your account requires one of the following IAM roles: Owner or Editor.

Comment: The document is wrong. Owner and Editor are legacy that existed before IAM. Both Owner and Editor will grant the required permission, but this is a huge overkill. The necessary App Engine role is `roles/appengine.appAdmin`

Comment: John, thanks I will try it!

Comment: John, did not work... adding this role does not enable the user to run the cron jobs!